# Require valid monetary input in either of one or two fields, but not both

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two fields, with name and ID saveamount and buyamount. I require one, and only one of the fields to be completed, with a valid monetary amount.

I've got the code to validate a monetary amount, and grouped the field names so the error appears in the right place. I need to expand the code so the error will also display where both fields are populated, or when neither field is populated.

```
<script>

jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "money",
    function(value, element) {
        var isValidMoney = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(value);
        return this.optional(element) || isValidMoney;
    },
    "Please enter a valid amount"
);


$("#myForm").validate({
rules: {
    saveamount: {
        money: true,
    },
    buyamount: {
        money: true,
        }
},
groups: {amountgroup: "saveamount buyamount"},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

    if (element.attr("name") == "saveamount" || element.attr("name") == "buyamount" ) {


      error.insertAfter("#buyamount");


    } else {


      error.insertAfter(element);


    }},
messages: {
            saveamount: "Please enter a valid monetary amount in one field only.",
            buyamount: "Please enter a valid monetary amount in one field only."
            }


});


         </script>
```

Comment: FYI - the "additional-methods.js" add-on for this plugin already contains a rule for currency.

Answer (score -1):

You can to use `require_from_group` and define number of fields in a group are complete.

```js
 jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "money",
    function(value, element) {
        var isValidMoney = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/.test(value);
        return this.optional(element) || isValidMoney;
    },
    "Please enter a valid amount"
);

$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    money: {
    money:true,
      require_from_group: [1, ".money-group"]
    },
    buyamount: {
    money:true,
      require_from_group: [1, ".money-group"]
    },
   
  },
   submitHandler: function(form,event) {
   alert("GO")
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
<label for="money">input1: </label>
<input class="money-group" id="money" name="money">
<br/>
<label for="buyamount">input2: </label>
<input class="money-group" id="buyamount" name="buyamount">
<br/>
 
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
```

Comment: Not really what the OP asked for.  When both are filled in, the form is valid.  He wants one or the other, not both filled and not both empty.

Comment: yes, least 1 of these fields is filled, please run my code :)

Comment: Your form is also valid when **BOTH** fields are filled out.  That is clearly not what the OP asked for:  *"I require **one, and only one** of the fields"*  AND *"I need ... the error will also display where **both fields** are populated"*.